# Agregar palabra a un array ubicado en otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, html, input

tengo un array de palabras en un archivo js y quiero añadir mediante otro html y js palabras al array original, pero cuando hago .push() al array me salta error en la consola. Comparto código:

```js
// Este array lo tengo en un archivo .js diferente
let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];

// Código del otro archivo
function agregarPalabra(){

    let dato = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();

    palabras.push(dato); // Acá es donde me salta el error

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id="texto">
    
<input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Agregar nueva palabra' onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>
```

Comment: Plantéate el uso de localStorage o sessionStorage para poder almacenar y compartir datos en javascript entre distintos HTML que no comparten los mismos scripts pero si el mismo dominio.

Comment: intenta haciendo una global de palabras, `window.palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];`, lo intente y me resulto, sin embargo no lo pongo como respuesta ya que no se si es lo que estas buscando, primero prueba así

Comment: Plantéate el uso de localStorage o sessionStorage no sabría como implementarlo. Mi error estuvo en que me faltó agregar el script al otro html, pero lo malo es que ahora me salta un nuevo error :/ . Comparto código nuevamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primer lugar hay varias cosas que no logro comprender en al forma en como esté implementando el código, una de ellas es que estén en archivos distintos y lo otro cuál es el objetivo de modificar el array si luego se va a borrar cuando actualice el navegador.

Como ya te comentaron el uso de localStorage sería el ideal para este escenario como y otro sería agregar una etiqueta `<input id="palabrasOcultas" type="hidden">` para que almacene los datos de manera temporal.

En el caso del localStorage puede implementar el codigo de abajo, **si no funciona aquí es por el window de stackoverflow, pero aquí sí ejecuta**: https://jsfiddle.net/0dv7yq6a/2/

```js
// ARCHIVO1.JS
let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];
// guardamos el array en localStorage con stringify
localStorage.setItem('palabras', JSON.stringify(palabras))


// ARCHIVO2.JS
function agregarPalabra(){
    let dato = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();
    // Obtenemos el array localStorage de palabras y lo convertimos en objeto con parse
    let palabrasLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("palabras"));
    // Agregamos el nuevo al array
    palabrasLocal.push(dato);
    // Lo pasamos por stringify para que se guarde como array
    let palabrasLocalNew = JSON.stringify(palabrasLocal);
    // Mostramos un alert para ver que todo este bien
    alert(palabrasLocalNew);
    // Guardamos el nuevo array
    localStorage.setItem('palabras', palabrasLocalNew);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id="texto">
<input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Agregar nueva palabra' onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>
```

Si desea que los datos que creó no se pierda al actualizar el navegador entonces hay crear una condicional que busque si existe el array "palabras" en localStorage, para eso borramos `localStorage.setItem('palabras', JSON.stringify(palabras))` y cambiarlo por:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("palabras") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('palabras', JSON.stringify(palabras))
}
```

Ejemplo de este codigo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/0dv7yq6a/1/

Recomendo leer bien como funciona localStorage: https://es.javascript.info/localstorage

Espero esto ayude.