# Recordar eventos o peticiones al recargar o al ir a pagina en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo una vista donde se filtran los registros por fecha que por defecto me muestra los registros del mes en curso y mediante inputs de tipo `date` me filtra los registros entre fechas.
Ahora utilizo el rango de fechas para mostrar únicamente los registros que quiero después en esa misma vista tengo un botón para crear un nuevo registro y todo funciona a la perfección, el único detalle es que al guardar el registro y redirigir de nuevo a la vista de todos los registros me pone los registros por el `Mes en curso`, en vez que me respete el filtrado por fechas.

trabajo con Livewire para el filtrado.

no he encontrado algo parecido por internet así que pensé que alguien me podría orientar en ese tema, aunque parece ser mas un tema de Javascript que de livewire o Laravel en si

Comment: No he podido entender muy bien su explicación pero a simple vista parece un problema de ambos y cada uno tiene una solución independiente. La idea en solución con JS es poder guardar en un lado la última fechas como por ejemplo localStorage, púede ver este ejemplo que hice para otra pregunta  a ver si le sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/535041/agregar-palabra-a-un-array-ubicado-en-otro-archivo-js/535218#535218 y aquí corre: https://jsfiddle.net/0dv7yq6a/1/

Comment: gracias por responder, le echare un vistazo mas a fondo parece ser similar a lo que busco, gracias

Comment: en pocas palabras quieres conservar las fechas ingresadas para el filtro una vez que la página se recarga?

Comment: si ese es el caso, lo que puedes hacer también es enviar por request esas fechas  y comprobar por ejemplo isset(request->get('fecha))) entonces colocas esa fecha en el input date de lo contrario un null

Comment: @HeynerMartinez si exactamente, probare de esta manera, gracias